# Is this source true?

Tags: source-identification

Q: After having bath (ghusl), sometimes semen releases after about 2-3 mins. Do I have to so the ghusl again?
A. After ejaculation, do not take a bath before one of the three points mentioned below is done:
a) Sleeping for a while.
b) Walking at least forty steps.
c) Urinating.
If one of the three was done and then a person took a bath and thereafter there was a release of semen, it will not be necessary to repeat the bath but Wudhu will break. Washing the area and changing or washing the soiled clothes will suffice.

This was on IslamQA and is it allowed to follow this rule

Source- https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askmufti/45118/semen-release-after-ghusl/

Comment: that answer if based on the hanafi fiqh.

Comment: The answer is based on the hanafi fiqh and it quotes the source Rad al-Muhtar رد المحتار a commentary of ibn 'Abidyyn one of the last great scholars of the hanafi fiqh. However it is rather unclear which part of the answer is quoted from this source.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I found the quote [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21613/155#p1) in رد المحتار and will later share and translate it to some extent. In the case my finding is correct, the mufti here changed the wording widely. However I'm not sure whether the mufti or me are missing something.

In this section the author Shams ad-Dyn at-Tumurtashi شمس الدين التمرتاشي in his Tanweer al-Absaar تنوير الأبصار (Commented by 'Ala' ad-Dyn al-Haskafi علاء الدين الحصكفي in his ad-Dur al-Mukhtar الدر المختار and commented as footnotes by ibn [Abidyyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abidin) محمد أمين بن عمر بن عبد العزيز عابدين الدمشقي in his Rad al-Muhtaar 'ala ad-Durri al-Mukhtar رد المحتار على الدر المختار) started quoting cases in which ghusl is obligatory -The first case was semen emission for both men and women and was quoted a page earlier [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21613/154#p1)- saying:
<sup>**NOTE:** I'll here show by example how this book is built, by quoting the statements of each of these scholars as seperated as possible in order to make ti possible to distinguish them.</sup>
 <sup>Please also note that I'll be translating from Arabic language and as these translations are of my own take them carefully!</sup> 
(At-Tumurtashi)

> وفرض
> ... And it was imposed...

(Al-Haskafi)

> **وفرض** الغسل
> **And the obligation** of ghusl. <sup>or: And gusl was imposed ...</sup>

(Ibn 'Abidyyn)

> (**قوله: وفرض الغسل**) الظاهر أنه أراد بالفرض ما يعم العلمي والعملي؛ لأنه عند رؤية مستيقظ بللا ليس مما ثبت بدليل لا شبهة فيه كما نبه عليه في الحلية؛ ولذا خالف فيه أبو يوسف كما سيأتي.
> (**His saying: And the obligation of washing**) It seems that he intended by imposing what prevails scientific and practical; Because if an awake person sees wetness is not something that has been proven with unsuspecting evidence, as it was pointed by the author of al-Hilyah. Therefore, Abu Yusuf violated it, as it will be presented (later).

Basically all three authors present the discussions inside the hanafi schoool of fiqh and may also address the views of other madhhabs.

As far as I know the fatwa choices of ibn 'Abidyyn are mostly those which later hanafi scholar follow, except if they practice some kind of ijtihad.

First of all we must be aware that different cases may apply here:

1. The semen which one may find after ghusl is a remnant from the earlier emission after intercourse.
   In this case it mostly is regarded as male semen on the man and it could be both female or male semen on the woman and here some scholars made a distinction.
2. The semen was produced due to a new desire or lust.

In the 1st case the majority view is that the ghusl which was performed is sufficient, however if one performed wudu' or prayed there could be an impact. The discussion of the hanafi madhhab according our reference will be shared later.
In the 2nd case the matter must be further analysed: did a new intercourse happen? Was it only madhy etc.? Depending on that a ruling will apply, on the validity of ghusl, wudu' or prayer.
Ibn 'Abidyyn in his discussion of semen emission and whether the observation of wetness alone can't be regarded as free of doubts about it being seemen and he displayed for example that the shafi'i school of fiqh regards semen emission due to beating or carrying heavy things as making ghusl obligatory, while hanafi's regard the lust and desire part as an important factor.

My understanding of the pages is that some Hanafi's make a distinction between men and women regarding semen emission after ghusl, if ghusl was done right after intercourse.

WORK IN PROGRESS TO BE CONTINUED!

Comment: Salam brother, was wondering whether you have anything to add to the current answer?

Comment: @Usman yes I should, but didn't have time.

Comment: That’s fine, don’t rush the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust islamqa.org, I remember hearing from others recommending islamqa.info instead, and I trust the latter.

No, if semen leaks out without ejaculation [i.e. no wet-dream/intercourse], there's no obligation to take bath, only ablution.

**Hadeeth:** https://sunnah.com/muslim:349

What's written in the ruling [ignoring its source] is to ensure there's no leak before the ablution, so that you don't need to repeat it, but it's not mandatory to do those steps in the ruling, nor you need to repeat your bath if there was no fast ejaculation of semen.

Comment: The source you put says a bath or ghusl is required when semen is emoted.

Comment: I wasn't clear, semen ejaculation means a quick flow after sexual pleasure [wet dream included], which means semen leakage due to any other reason doesn't require bathing.  **Hadeeth:** https://sunnah.com/nasai:193  **Ruling:** https://islamqa.info/en/answers/93027/things-that-make-ghusl-obligatory

Comment: Right ok I get you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).